# Linux. launch python script from .config/upstart/ in a visible terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

If i add a launcher in .config/upstart like:

start_python.conf

```
start on desktop-start
exec python myscript.py
stop on desktop-end
```

myscript.py is basically a neverending while-loop that does some voodoo...

If i try the above will it start when the machine boots up. 
But it is invisible (can be found with ps aux | grep python after boot).

**I want it launched in a visible terminal window so i can monitor it.** How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal application should have option accepting command to run within, see `man terminal-app-name` or `terminal-app-name --help`. There is `Konsole` example:

```
konsole -e python myscript.py
```

I suppose you have [gnome-terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) as a default terminal emulator, so either

```
gnome-terminal --command="python myscript.py"
```

or

```
gnome-terminal --execute python myscript.py
```

should work.